# Столица Мозамбика - Мапуту или Мапуто?

Tags: ономастика, названия

Как будет правильно назвать этот город по-русски?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мозамбик в прошлом - португальская колония, и написание Maputo - португальское. В соответствии с португальско-русской практической транскрипцией (а ей следуют, в частности, при передаче географических названий) *в безударном положении в конце слова* "о" в русском передаётся как "у".

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Португальско-русская_практическая_транскрипция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Отсюда и фиксация варианта "**Мапуту**" в словарях. Аналогично, Сан-Паулу (São Paul**o**; сочетание ão передаётся по отдельному правилу) в Бразилии и т. п. Иные варианты ненормативны.

Answer (score 0):

В словаре собственных имен русского языка Ф. Л. Агеенко зафиксирован вариант Мапуту. Та же рекомендация в советском энциклопедическом словаре 1979 г.

Answer (score 0):

"Словарь собственных имён русского языка" Агеенко утверждает, что *Мапут**у***.

> Мапуту, нескл. (Делагоа) (бух., Мозамбик)
>
> Мапуту, нескл. (б. Лоренсу-Маркиш) (столица Мозамбика)